# How to setValue value in useFormHook to form on re render in function component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-form

I am creating a project where we can add and edit a user. For editing a user I am sending id as a url parameter using `react-router-dom` `Link` from one page to other and with the `useParams` hook. I am fetching that `id`. This `id` I am using for setting the data to form. I have all users stored in `redux store`. Now the question is when I reload the page the data is taking some time to load from `redux store` and the `setValue` of `useFormHook` is throwing an error.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { fetchData } from "./utils/index";
import { UpdateStudent} from "./utils/index";
function Update() {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.students);
  console.log(users);
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors, isDirty, isValid },
  } = useForm({ mode: "onChange" });
  let { id } = useParams();
  var user = students && students.filter((u) => u.id === parseInt(id));
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setStudents(users);
  }, [users]);



useEffect(() => {
    setValue("name", user.name);
  }, []);
  const onUpdate = (data) => {
   
  };

  return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onUpdate)}>
              <div>
                <input
                  {...register("name", {
                  })}
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Name"
             
                />
              </div>
                <button
                  color="primary"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={!isDirty || !isValid}
                >
                  Save
                </button>
              
            </form>
         
  );
}

export default Update;
```

Comment: `user` will either only ever be a falsey value if `students` is falsey, or it will be an array since `array.filter` returns an array. I don't see how `setValue("name", user.name);` could ever work. Why are you duplicating the `students` state into local state? This is an anti-pattern in React.

Comment: Drew Reese : Do you have any solution for this?.How to implement it in a better way

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve this in my current project is that I split the component into 2, one component gets the user, one is only rendered when the user is available.

```js
function Update() {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.students);
  console.log(users);
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  let { id } = useParams();
  var user = students && students.filter((u) => u.id === parseInt(id));
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setStudents(users);
  }, [users]);

  if(!user) return null; // or progress indicator

  return <UpdateForm user={user} />
}


function UpdateForm({user})
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors, isDirty, isValid },
  } = useForm({ mode: "onChange" });
  
  useEffect(() => {
      setValue("name", user.name);
    }, []);
    const onUpdate = (data) => {
     
    };
  }, [user.name]);

  return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onUpdate)}>
              <div>
                <input
                  {...register("name", {
                  })}
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Name"
             
                />
              </div>
                <button
                  color="primary"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={!isDirty || !isValid}
                >
                  Save
                </button>
              
            </form>
         
  );
}

export default Update;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the issues I mentioned in comment above, the code doesn't handle when the `students` state updates. You could simplify the code a bit and consume the `students` state directly instead of duplicating it locally. Since the redux state is sometimes not available on the initial render cycle you'll need to use an `useEffect` with a dependency on the state used to update form state.

```
function Update() {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.students);
  
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors, isDirty, isValid },
  } = useForm({ mode: "onChange" });

  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = users?.filter((u) => u.id === Number(id));
    if (user) {
      setValue("name", user.name);
    }
  }, [users]); // <-- add users to dependency to update form state

  ...

  if (/* no form state yet */) {
    return "Loading..."; // or some loading indicator
  }

  return (
    ... // form UI
  );
}
```

Comment: Drew Reese : How can i check here form state `if (/* no form state yet */) {
    return "Loading..."; 
  }`

Comment: @AsmatWani You could use either the [getValues](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/getvalues) function to get the field value and check if populated, or since it's just the one input use the fact that `user` is defined or not (*would necessitate being moved out of the effect and update the effect's dependency*).